# Testing C code with googletest (Google C++ Testing Framework)

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

I'm trying to test C code with googletest but I'm having some problems when my C header files are included in the C++ test file because the g++ compiler handle them as C++ headers.

I've tried to include these headers inside `extern "C" {}` with no success.

Is there a way g++ compiler can handle these headers as C ones?

Comment: It's strange that `extern "C" { }` doesn't take care of it -- what's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: C syntax features like `typedef struct A *A; struct A { A a; };` raise errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

extern "C" only changes link stage name mangling. If you are using C features that aren't shared by C++ then you are SOL

Comment: Yes, is there a way g++ could handle the header as a C one?

Comment: No. If you want to intermingle C and C++ modules you must do it at the linking stage. A single binary object file can only be compiled with one language's rules

Comment: What deos SOL mean?